# Using science, could sound vibrations & tremors be the reason for the wall of Jericho to fall?

Tags: joshua, science

> Joshua 6 NASB
>   15 Then on the seventh day they rose early at the dawning of the day and **marched around the city in the same manner seven times; only on that day they marched around the city seven times.** 16 At the seventh time, when the priests blew the trumpets, Joshua said to the people, “Shout! For the Lord has given you the city. ......... 20 So the people shouted, and [g]priests blew
>   the trumpets; and when the people heard the sound of the trumpet, the
>   people shouted with a **great shout and the wall fell down [h]flat**, so
>   that the people went up into the city, every man straight [i]ahead,
>   and they took the city. ................

Could we say that the science behind sound vibrations and tremors caused by a large crowd of people marching, and the sound from the blowing trumpets caused the wall of Jericho to fall?

Comment: I dont think theres enough trumpets in the world. This was a miracle from God.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the text but about the physical feasibility of some hypothetical event (that it's described in the Bible is irrelevant).

Answer (score 2):

Either low frequency sound or ultra sound of sufficient strength to make thick stone walls collapse (if such a sound exists, as yet) would kill everyone in the vicinity. I had a kidney stone shattered with sound waves, at St Thomas's Hospital in London in 1984, and they had to time the pulses of sound in between my heart beats to avoid me fibrillating and dying in the sound bath.

Also, I used to live a mile away from [Hampden Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampden_Park) football ground in Glasgow in my teens and we could hear the 'Hampden Roar' of the 40,000 crowd. But the stadium never fell apart.

It is true that marching soldiers are commanded to march out of step when crossing delicate structures like wooden bridges or swinging bridges as sympathetic resonance can, indeed, cause bridge collapse but I am not aware of any report of a stone or brick-built bridge so suffering.

The Millenium Bridge in London famously exhibited this phenomenon and dampers had to be added to it.

But the city of Jericho would require an earthquake to cause destructive damage of the kind reported in scripture and that earthquake would have to exactly coincide with the army of Israel and the sounding of the trumpets.

Such a 'coincidence' is, in itself, miraculous.